# Pane cutting off when using light effects and perspective camera

Tags: javafx, light

I have encountered yet another problem with javaFX light effects. When using perspective camera to follow player in 2D world, everything works fine, until I add light effects!

The CYAN color represents the background.. When light effects are ON, the level pane does not render at the edges of the scene and the background can be seen instead. This makes the bottom and right side of my levels invisible and therefore unplayable. In the full screen mode it is even worse!

here is my demonstration code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.Light;
import javafx.scene.effect.Lighting;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class dd extends Application {

PerspectiveCamera cam = new PerspectiveCamera(false);

public void start(Stage alku) throws Exception {
    Pane testpane = new Pane();

    Rectangle background = new Rectangle(500, 500);
    background.setFill(Color.CYAN);

    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(500, 300);

    Lighting lig = new Lighting();
    Light.Point l = new Light.Point();
    l.setX(200);
    l.setY(150);
    l.setZ(20);
    l.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    lig.setLight(l);

    rec.setFill(Color.RED);

    testpane.getChildren().addAll(background, rec);

    Scene scene = new Scene(testpane, 300, 300);
    cam.setTranslateX(30);
    cam.setTranslateY(30);

    alku.setTitle("TEST");
    alku.setScene(scene);

    rec.setEffect(lig);
    scene.setCamera(cam);
    alku.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}

}
```

If you remove the camera or the light, the "rec" renders normally again. Just adjust the window size to see the problem better.
So the main question I have:
Is this a bug? If not, how can this rendering issue be solved without sacrificing lights and camera?

Comment: [mcve] please (mind the __M__!) And put a bit more effort into formatting the code to make it readable.

Comment: @kleopatra Okay! I realized it was too long. The problem should be easier to understand now!

Comment: My problem could be related to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192113/how-to-use-parallel-camera-javafx